# Adjusting margin between buttons according to screen size

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I have navigation buttons on my mobile site. I want to change the margin between the buttons according to different screen sizes such that gap between button expands buttons from one end to other. Tried setting margin to auto in CSS button nothing happening.

This is CSS for the button

```
.button {
    background-color: #4CAF50; /* Green */
    border: none;
    color: white;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 16px;
    margin: 3px auto;
    -webkit-transition-duration: 0.4s; /* Safari */
    transition-duration: 0.4s;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.button1 {
    background-color: white; 
    color: black; 
    border: 2px solid #4CAF50;
}

.button1:hover {
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    color: white;

}
```

and html code

```
<div id="button">



    <a href='<?php if($prev == "#") { echo $random_url; } else { echo $prev; } ?>' class="button button1" id="prev" title="Previous Pic"><i class="fa fa-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></i>&nbsp;Prev</a>

                                     <a href='<?php { echo $random_url; } ?>' class="button button1" id="next" title="Random Pic">Random<i class="fa fa-random"></i></a>

                                     <a href='<?php if($next == "#") { echo $random_url; } else { echo $next; } ?>' class="button button1" id="next" title="Random Pic">Next&nbsp;<i class="fa fa-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>

                    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

- **Media Queries**

  `@media (max-width: 600px) {
    .button {
      margin: 10px 10px; // Vertical, Horizontal
    }
  }`

- **Bootstrap Grid**

Add following class to a grid `.col-offset-*-*`

- **`VW` and `VH`**

`.button {
     margin: 1vh 1vw; // Vertical, Horizontal
  }`

I had recommend to use media queries since I am assuming you are already using these either some responsive CSS framework or grid system.

Comment: Tried using media query, when i  select ip 6 it margin is fine, but when i select smaller screen e.g ip5 last button is displayed on second line

Comment: It happens because your button has not enough space to fit smaller screen sizes, it is common to fit them vertically when the width is too small to make your content readable. I suspect you could have done a bad approach to your problem, I can advice you to previously plan your content and therefore design for it so you can think on how you could implement your ideas. You might like to check **mobile first**, and **bootstrap**/**foundation**/**materializecss**, either any other alike tools.

Comment: Try to keep your solution simple and clean, it should not be a problem at all. However this kind of details are common to bring some headaches, and further could keep your responsiveness buggy. You should play with what the environment offers you. If it jumps try to add vertical margin instead of horizontal. You can lower font-size so they fit but is it a good idea ? Is it readable ? is it user friendly for the user ? Does not seem so

Comment: I meant to say when smaller screen size selected the margin didn't changed accordingly, if I set max-width to 300 , it fits the screen and displayed in 1 line, but then margins do not change for larger screen size, I guess there is something missing, and I have little knowledge regarding it so I am unable to detect